# When to use (and not to use) Jinja2 loaders

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm working with Jinja2 for the first time. When would I want to specify a loader and when would I not want to specify a loader? I have seen examples using loaders and examples not using loaders, and I'm a bit confused.

I did read the documentation here: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/api/#loaders. I'm hopeful that you can explain it in a simpler way for me.

My end goal is to produce an HTML string that I can embed / insert in an email.

Comment: Can you explain what you are using Jinja for and why you think you need a Loader at all?

Comment: I updated my post to address your questions. (Thank you for letting me know that I should add this information.)

Comment: As usual, if you are able to do things without a loader, you don't need to use it. `I did read the documentation here: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/api/#loaders. I'm hopeful that you can explain it in a simpler way for me.` - Explain **what**? What is not clear?

Comment: Why do you need to implement *your own Loader*? What are you thinking you're missing from those provided? Flask uses the FilesystemLoader by default, for example

Comment: Question: Why use a loader? How do I know when I need to use a loader?

Cricket, I do not plan to implement my own loader. I cannot decide whether or not I need to specify one when I instantiate Environment or Template.